# General tab is missing in xcode 10

Tags: reactjs, react-native-ios

I would like to register my provisioning certificate while creating an **IPA** file in *React Native* iOS.When I try to apply my provisioning certificate, the general tab is not there in **XCode**.

Any input would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Double click on certificates its automatically added into Xcode

Comment: Where are certificates?